# Tracing the idea "Reality is an unstructured flux and our cognitive system is responsible for creating the structure we perceive"

Tags: reality, cognitive-sciences, cognition

I think reality is independent (I reject a solipsistic point of view) but also that reality is much less than we see because is a continuous and unstructured flux  structured only by our cognitive system. I think primary notions like entity and class are cognitive axioms, and are not related to the reality but are created by our cognitive system in order to survive, to extrapolate previous experiences to new situations and thus anticipate reality.

So this idea is floating around, and a lot of things I've read point that way, but I would like to quote some authority. At least the first who thought about it and some prominent modern authority with a quote if possible. Of course more authorities are welcome.
I thought I've read Nietzsche questioning the nature of reality and logic in The Gay Science and I've been exposed to some cognitive ideas. But I'm really interested in tracing the idea.

Who thought that way then and now?
Who speculated about it and who derived that idea scientifically?

Comment: This is a crude version of the idea [traditionally associated with Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant): sensibility delivers unstructured manifold of sensations which is then framed by our forms of sensibility (space and time), understanding and reason. Given the framing part, it is pointless to talk about what the "reality itself" is like before the framing, we cannot possibly have any idea. That "everything is in flux" is the idea that goes back to [Heraclitus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heraclitus/#Flu), but he did not put any emphasis on our framing of it.

Comment: That means that our minds have to somehow be connected in real-time in a way that causes them to derive related experiences from the same structureless nonsense.  This seems unlikely.  So the odds are that reality contains at least as much as we see, at least when we see it in common.  To say it is other that what we get from it, cannot mean it is strictly less, unless you think we are all psychic.  Kant sandwiches the phenomena we interpret between a source in noumena and a basic shared human nature, to make it credible that we tend to agree.  But then those would be parts of reality, too.